# Can app get approximate location even if current location is off?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, geolocation, google-geolocation

I'm brainstorming the functionality of a mobile app when "Current Location" is off.

Is it possible to have an idea of where a user is located even if "Current Location" is off?

I'm developing a mobile app whose only purpose is to display the closest `Joe's Florida Tacos` locations to user's current location. It will have the usual list (closest first) and a map with the markers. The app doesn't have any use outside of Florida.

With "Location Services" ON, the app will opens it will display a list of locations, sorted by distance.

If "Location Services" is OFF, then I would like to find an approximate location. Is this possible? This "approximate location" is a starting point that I can use to display data.

Comment: "Will the list be empty or will it show everything? And let's say that the user switches to map, what will the map display?"  These are not questions we can answer for you.  You need to ask your customer, or just make a decision.  Perhaps poll some potential users and ask them, or look at how similar apps behave.

Comment: You're right. I'll delete.